# Jquery toggle label/button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a very basic toggle script which works fine but I would like to toggle the label so it shows show first then hide

my html is:

```
    <button type="button" class="show">Show</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="info">#info</div>
<div id="edit">#edit</div>
```

and my jquery is

```
$("#edit").hide();
$(".show").click(function(){
$("#info, #edit").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

css is:

```
#info {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 background-color:green;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;   
}

#edit {
 position:absolute;
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;  
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the jQuery code, did you wrap it into $(document).ready()?

Comment: No sure what your mean ? The content is hidden at first load but you want it hidden ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(){alert('run this code when document is fully loaded')}`. If you have jQuery code above the html elements they do not exist as of yet so your jQuery wont execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
$('button').text($('button').text() === 'Show' ? "Hide" : "Show");
```

So your JavaScript looks like this:

```
$("#edit").hide(); 
$("show").click(function(){
    $("#info, #edit").fadeToggle("slow");
    $('button').text($('button').text() === 'Show' ? "Hide" : "Show");
});
```

That line toggles the button text depending on the current value.

Also, your colored boxes move a bit when toggling because the `left:0` is only on one DIV.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xerbefmg/